# insert into form doesn't insert into table ? with codeigniter framework

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, post, methods

database details:

dbtable : guests
dbcolumns : id (A_I), guestname, guestemail

when i submit a data it's only refresh the page and take no action i'm beginner please tell me where's the problem and why

i made insert form by basic php and i passed but with codeigniter maybe i'm not fully understood yet looks like my experience about 1% or 5% :D :D

Controller/Guests.php :

```
<?php

class Guests extends CI_Controller {


   public function index($page = 'guests')
        {

        if ( ! file_exists(APPPATH.'/views/main/'.$page.'.php'))
        {
                // Whoops, we don't have a page for that!
                show_404();
        }

        $data['title'] = ucfirst($page);
        $data['pagedesc'] = 'Guests List';
        $this->load->view('include/header', $data);
        $this->load->model('guests_model');
        $data['records'] = $this->guests_model->getAll();
        $this->load->view('main/guests', $data);
        $this->load->view('include/footer', $data);

        }
   public function addnewguest($page = 'Add New Guest')
        {

        if ( ! file_exists(APPPATH.'/views/main/addnewguest.php'))
        {
                // Whoops, we don't have a page for that!
                show_404();
        }

        $data['title'] = ucfirst($page);
        $data['pagedesc'] = 'Please Fill Informations Below';
        $this->load->view('include/header', $data);                                 // loaded the header
        $this->load->model('guests_model');                                         // loaded the model 
        $this->load->view('main/addnewguest', $data);                               // loaded add new form
        if($this->input->post('createnew')) {                                             // if click add send information to addnewguestpost() function in the guest_model file
            $this->guests_model->addnewguestfunc();
        }
        $this->load->view('include/footer', $data);                                 // loaded the footer

        }
}
```

views/main/addnewguest.php

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="<?php echo site_url('guests/addnewguest'); ?>" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="guestname" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Guest Name</label>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <input type="text" name="guestname" class="form-control" id="guestname" placeholder="Guest Name ...">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="guestemail" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Guest Email</label>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <input type="text" name="guestemail" class="form-control" id="guestemail" placeholder="Guest Email ..">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="createnew">Add</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

models/guests_model.php

```
<?php

class Guests_model extends CI_Model {


    public function getAll() {

        $query = $this->db->get('guests');


        if($query->num_rows() > 0){
            return $query->result(); 
        } else {
            return FALSE;
        }

    }
    public function addnewguestfunc() {

        $data = array(

                'guestname' => $this->input->post('guestname'),
                'guestemail' => $this->input->post('guestemail')

        );




        $this->db->insert('guests', $data);

    }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved !!**

> forgot change button to input because i copied it from bootstrap basic templates for practicing ..

views/main/addnewguest.php after change button to input :

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="<?php echo site_url('guests/addnewguest'); ?>" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="guestname" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Guest Name</label>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <input type="text" name="guestname" class="form-control" id="guestname" placeholder="Guest Name ...">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="guestemail" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Guest Email</label>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <input type="text" name="guestemail" class="form-control" id="guestemail" placeholder="Guest Email ..">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="createnew">Add</input>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```